# Convert excel named Range to a collection of rows

Tags: vba, excel, collections, multidimensional-array, named-ranges

I currently have a method which takes in a dynamic named range in excel and converts it to a 2D array.

I need to do some iterations to the data and carry out a Delete function if a certain column contains a value. I have looked at the options out there for deleting rows in 2d array using transpose and temp array and since my data is fairly large I am looking at other data structures that would make it easier to delete entire rows.

I want to convert a dynamic named range into a collection in vba. This collection will have a key the row number and as item should have all the data for that row.  Basically I would need the ability to iterate through each value in that range like I can do with a 2D array but also the ability to delete a row efficiently and with less hassle than using a 2D array.

Anybody have an idea on how I can achieve this?

```
Dim srcArray () As Variant
Dim srcRange As Range
srcRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("myNamedRange")
srcArray = srcRange.Value
Dim rowNr As Long
dim colNr As Long

 for rowNr = 1 to UBound(srcArray,1)
         if srcArray(rowNr, 9) = "testString" Then Call DeleteRowSub(srcArray, rowNr)
  Next rowNr
```

DeleteRowSub will be a sub which will delete a given row based on the index of that row. I want to get away from that and just be able to say something like srcCollection.Remove(index) with index being the row nr.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: look up jagged arrays but a better approach would be to use an autofilter. Plenty of resources around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no secret to this. It's just housekeeping.

```
Function ReadRangeRowsToCollection(r As Range) As Collection
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim rangeArr As Variant
    Dim rowArr As Variant
    Dim c As Collection

    'Read range content to Variant array
    rangeArr = r.Value 

    'Now transfer shit to collection
    Set c = New Collection
    For iRow = 1 To r.Rows.Count
        ReDim rowArr(1 To r.Columns.Count)
        For iCol = 1 To r.Columns.Count
            rowArr(iCol) = rangeArr(iRow, iCol)
        Next iCol
        c.Add rowArr, CStr(iRow)
    Next iRow

    Set ReadRangeRowsToCollection = c
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Dim c As Collection
Set c = ReadRangeRowsToCollection(Range("myNamedRange"))
c.Remove 1 ' remove first row from collection
```

Note: I haven't looked at edge cases; for example this will fail if the range is one cell only. Up to you to fix it.

Comment: Thank you soo much. This is exactly what I needed. You have saved me a good few hours. I was struggling to get my head around the logic.